# Financial Department Bitcoin

Tags: blockchain.info

I wanted to send bitcoins to my wallet from my trading account and did not receive anything. A short time later I got from
Fiancial Department Bitcoin received the following message:
Your payment of BITCOINS is ready to be processed and is already on BLOCKCHAIN.
This department wants to pay me bitcoins for a fee and I don't know if this is real? Has anyone ever had anything to do with it and can you trust this depatment?

Comment: This sounds like a scam.

Comment: So this service is holding your money, but wants you to send *more* money, to pay a fee? This is pretty obviously a red flag for it being scam, if they were legitimate they could just take the fees off the money they are already holding for you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem right. I wouldn't trust them. I would suspect fraud.

> **Financial Department Bitcoin**

As I'm sure you know, The Bitcoin currency and Bitcoin network is peer to peer and has no departments. So no financial departments.

In normal English, or business English this phrase doesn't make much sense. Some kind of business would have a financial department but those sorts of departments are not usually split by currency. Generally there would be an accounting department that might communicate with creditors and debtors, there might be some kind of sales department or customer services department that communicates with retail customers.

> **my trading account**

If you have an account you are dealing with one of the many thousands of businesses that make money by selling services to people who want to invest or trade in Bitcoin. There are lots of fraudulent businesses that are just invented to trick people out of money. There are also some genuine businesses of this sort but many people find it hard to tell genuine businesses from fraudulent ones.

Finance departments are usually different, here's one definition:

> Finance Department is the part of an organization that is responsible for acquiring funds for the firm, managing funds within the organization and planning for the expenditure of funds on various assets.

So in most businesses - the finance department mostly manages internal matters - it is generally not one that routinely interacts with retail customers.

For example a car manufacturer would have a finance department that might obtain funds for a new factory. They might not routinely be involved in selling cars to distributors and certainly not involved in selling cars to car-drivers.

Of course businesses are free to organise themselves as they wish and can name their departments whatever they want.

> **This department wants to pay me bitcoins for a fee and I don't know if this is real?**

If the fees were *not* made very clear right at the start, before you placed any money in this trading account -- then you are very likely the victim of fraud.

Comment: +1 I admire your grit to suss out this sort of situation again and again.